# How does the ImageElement.onload event work?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events

I genuinely just cannot find documentation for the 'onload' event on `img` HTML elements.

I recently used it in a React project after someone suggested it to me, and it seemed to fire the event after the `img` element was fully loaded in the DOM. That's what I needed, but I can't find any real documentation on it or when the event actually fires.

Then, as if to contradict my success, I played with it in a codepen (linked below), and had a couple different results.

I read an [Here](https://stackoverflow.com) that suggests the event fires after the 'image source is loaded', which seems to line up with what I've observed.

So to sum up, I have two questions:

1. Does someone have a good link to documentation for this event? It doesn't seem related to document.onload or window.onload- and those are the only things I could find
2. If I add the source after appending the element, then and do an action after the event fires, will that mean It's safe to assume the image element is fully loaded on the page and the styling information (such as the `img` element's final width and height) will be correct?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/takinabradley/pen/GRYvpdG?editors=1011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the full specification about when the browser will fire a `load` event on `<img>` tag: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#updating-the-image-data

A summarise of the specification to answer your 2nd question:

- If the image `src` comes from the [list of available images](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#list-of-available-images) (Images that has been loaded since your page is open)

  - Trigger the `load` event immediately
- If the resource type and data of the `src` corresponds to a supported image format:

  - `load` event will only be fired when the status is [completely available](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#img-all) (The user agent has obtained all of the image data and at least the image dimensions are available)
- If the resource type of the `src` is `multipart/x-mixed-replace`

  - `load` event will only be fired when at least "one body part has been completely decoded", which also guarantees the image dimension is known

---

For your Codepen, the problem is `window.getComputedStyle` cannot obtain the style of your element if it is not inserted to the DOM yet. The image data is already loaded but `window.getComputedStyle` is unable to obtain it. You can try to use `width` and `height` property of the element instead. (`e.target.width` and `e.target.height` in your `logComputedWidthAndHeight`)

Comment: This was somewhat helpful, I know you can't help the spec being opaque.

I understand that if the event fires *before* the the element is appended to the DOM, it's expected that `window.getComputedStyle` won't find the styles.

What I'm more curious about is `imageElem2`. If the source is added after the `img` element is appended, and then the `load` event fires, is it safe to assume that the computed styles that I get at that point (like width and height) are going to be accurate to the final product I expect to be rendered on the screen? It *seems* to be the case, but I wanna verify

Comment: @takinabradley Based on the specification it seems to be clear that at least the dimension information (width and height) will be correct by the time `load` event fires. However, it doesn't guarantee the image is fully loaded in the case where the content type is `multipart/x-mixed-replace`

Comment: After another overview of what you linked and a little more testing, it seems you're probably right. 

I was afraid maybe it meant that the browser had obtained the images width and height, but may not have necessarily known exactly how the image would be displayed on the page by then. On closer inspection it seems that it likely does prepare the image for presentation by the time the load event fires. 

You've been a great help! I did happen to find one mention of the event on MDN under the `complete` attribute of images. Wish I saw earlier, and there was a page dedicated to it.